# Am I writing the linear program in PuLP correctly ? any suggestions on improving code or alternative methods?

Tags: python-2.7, pulp

I am new to Python and i'm trying to write up a linear program using PuLP.

**Background information:**

*Z_row_col* - dictionary of dictionary of matrices representing a 16x16 Matrix 
              of 32x32 matrices.

*C* - similar dimension of Z_row_col. C contains zeros and ones where zeros 
      indicate the positions of Z_row_col that equals zero and ones indicate the 
      positions of Z_row_col that is greater than zero.

*Z_row_marg_sum* -  a 1x16 vector of 1x32 vectors that represent the desired row 
                    sum of Z_row_col

*Z_col_marg_sum* - a 16x1 vector of 32x1 vectors that represent the desired column sum of Z_row_col

**Linear Programming**

The objective is to maximize the entire sum of Z_row_col (sum of all 16x16x32x32 elements)

Constraint

1. row sum of Z_row_col equals to Z_row_marg_sum
2. column sum of Z_roW_col equals to Z_col_marg_sum
3. Z >= C*errac, where errac is a small positive number

**Code**

```
# error acceptance
errac = 0.0001

# define LP problem
prob = pulp.LpProblem('IRIO',pulp.LpMaximize)

# decision variables
x_var = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('flows',
                          [(row,col,m,k) for row in Z_row_col
                                         for col in Z_row_col
                                         for m in range(len(industry))
                                         for k in range(len(industry))],
                          lowBound=0,upBound=None,cat = pulp.LpContinuous)
# objective function
prob += pulp.lpSum(x_var[(row,col,m,k)] * c[row][col][m,k] for row in Z_row_col
                                                           for col in Z_row_col
                                                           for m in range(len(industry))
                                                           for k in range(len(industry)))

# constraints
# row sum constraint
for row in Z_row_col:
    for m in range(len(industry)):
        prob += pulp.lpSum(x_var[(row,col,m,k)] for col in Z_row_col
                                                for k in range(len(industry))) == Z_row_marg_sum[row][m]
# column sum constraint
for col in Z_row_col:
    for k in range(len(industry)):
        prob += pulp.lpSum(x_var[(row,col,m,k)] for row in Z_row_col
                                                for m in range(len(industry))) == Z_col_marg_sum[col][k]
# non-zero constraint
for row in Z_row_col:
    for col in Z_row_col:
        for m in range(len(industry)):
            for k in range(len(industry)):
                prob += Z_row_col[row][col][m,k] >= c[row][col][m,k] * errac

prob.solve()
```

The code gives me **'RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp'** starting at the row constraint. This is kind of expected because i have (16x16x32x32 =  262,144) variables.

*Am i writing this LP problem correctly? and i writing the code correctly? do you have any suggestions on how to make this LP work? any suggestions on a better representation of the matrices/vectors?*

Comment: I I were you Id print out 
```pulp.lpSum(x_var[(row,col,m,k)] for col in Z_row_col
                                                for k in range(len(industry)))```

and 
```Z_row_marg_sum[row][m]```

and make sure one is a linear expression and the other is a constant. That error usually occurs when you are not putting the right things together to form a constraint